# Running multiple async tasks in a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have two lists: queries and search_engines. I want to get each query and run a search on its corresponding search engine. I want to however do this concurrently in order to save some time. I am totally new to asynchronous programming and this is my attempt to do it. I keep getting an "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop" error.

```
import asyncio
import time


queries = ['messi', 'ronaldo', 'iniesta', 'xavi', 'ramos']
engines = ['Google', 'Google', 'Bing', 'Duckduckgo', 'Google']
async def get_queries():
    for query, engine in zip(queries, engines):
        if engine == 'Google':
            gtask = asyncio.create_task((google_search.get_domain_description(query)))
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        if engine == 'Bing':
            btask = asyncio.create_task(print(bing_search.get_domain_description(query)))
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
        if engine == 'Duckduckgo':
            dtask = asyncio.create_task(print(duckduckgo_search.get_domain_description(query)))
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

                                        
asyncio.run(get_queries())
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside a jupyter notebook? It already has an event loop running so you’d use `await` instead of `asyncio.run`. Also, rather than all of those `sleep` calls you’ll probably have a better result if you use `asyncio.gather` to await all of your tasks at once.

Comment: @dirn yes, it's in a Jupyter notebook. I will look into `asyncio.gather`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import asyncio

SEARCH_ENGINES = {
    'Google': google_search,
    'Bing': bing_search,
    'Duckduckgo': duckduckgo_search
}

async def get_query(engine, query):
    await SEARCH_ENGINES[engine].get_domain_description(query)

async def main():
    queries = ['messi', 'ronaldo', 'iniesta', 'xavi', 'ramos']
    engines = ['Google', 'Google', 'Bing', 'Duckduckgo', 'Google']
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[get_query(engine, query) for query, engine in zip(queries, engines)])

asyncio.run(main())
```